# How to initialize an array of Vec?

Tags: rust

I want to initialize a (fixed length) array of (variable length) vectors, like:

```
let array_of_vec: [Vec<i32>; 10] = [Vec::new(); 10];
```

But I'm getting:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<i32>: std::marker::Copy` is not satisfied
  |
2 |     let array_of_vec: [Vec<i32>; 10] = [Vec::new(); 10];
  |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::marker::Copy` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<i32>`
  |
  = note: the `Copy` trait is required because the repeated element will be copied
```

Is there any workaround for this restriction like initializing the array with an invalid value and then filling it using a loop?

Comment: `let array_of_vec: [Vec<i32>; 10] = Default::default();`